# ¿Como marcar un checkbox de un datatable Primeng?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular2-template, angular-datatables

Tengo este array de información this.userLanguage = response.lstLOV; que contiene estos datos:

```
0:{languageId:"en",languageName:"English",seleccion:true},
1:{languageId:"es",languageName:"Español",seleccion:false}...
```

En mi tabla los muestro así:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="userLanguage" name="userLang" dataKey="key">
 <p-column [style]="{'max-width':'300px'}" field="languageName" header="Nombre de Idioma"></p-column>
 <p-column [style]="{'max-width':'300px'}" field="languageId" header="Código"></p-column>
 <p-column field="seleccion" header="Estado">
  <ng-template let-col let-userLanguage="rowData" pTemplate="body">
   <p-checkbox name="seleccion" [ngModel]="userLanguage[col.field]" binary="true">
   </p-checkbox>
  </ng-template>
 </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Pero me los muestras todos en check, como si todos estuvieran activados

Answer (score 1):

El componente p-column permite definir contenido personalizado mediante ng-template.

```
<div>

      <p-dataTable [value]="personas">
        <p-column field="nombre" header="Nombre"></p-column>
        <p-column field="apellido" header="Apellido"></p-column>
        <p-column field="menor" header="Menor">
          <ng-template let-col let-persona="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <p-checkbox [ngModel]="persona[col.field]"  binary="true">
            </p-checkbox>
          </ng-template>
        </p-column>
      </p-dataTable>
    </div>
```

El archivo app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  personas;

  constructor() {

    this.personas = [
      { nombre: 'Perona 1', apellido: 'Persona', menor: false },
      { nombre: 'Perona 2', apellido: 'Persona 2', menor: true },
      { nombre: 'Perona 3', apellido: 'Persona 3', menor: false },
      { nombre: 'Perona 4', apellido: 'Persona 4', menor: true },
      { nombre: 'Perona 5', apellido: 'Persona 5', menor: false }
    ];
  }

}
```

Comment: Lo probé pre no funciono.

Comment: que error te sale??

Comment: El código que he subido me funciona correctamente

Comment: Hola Thakur, lo modifique pero me los muestra todos en check

Comment: Quieres decir que te marca todos los checkboxes como activos?